# Handle foreach by-ref in PHP 7

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, pass-by-reference, php-7

So far we've been using PHP 5.5 and everything seemed to be flowing too good with the code. Since upgrading it to 7 most of the foreach() seems to be having inconsistent behaviour.

For eg: Consider the snippet below:

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c');
self::testForeach($array);
.
.
.
// $array is passed by reference
public static function testForeach(&$array) {

  foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    //produces a, b as an output in PHP 5
    //produces a, b, c as an output in PHP 7
    var_dump($val);

    if ($val == 'b') {
      //remove 'c' from the array
      unset($array[2]);
    }
  }
}
```

Behaviour in PHP 5.5:

> $array is passed by reference to testForeach() function. So removing "c" from $array inside the loop would directly modify the original array. Hence, the iterated values would be a, b and not c as it gets removed from the array in between.

Behaviour in PHP 7:

> $array is passed by reference to testForeach() function. When $array is looped over foreach(), a copy is made say $arrayCopy (according to the doc) which is being iterated over the loop. So removing "c" value from $array would have no effect and will loop all the values contained in the $arrayCopy. 
>   Hence the output - a, b, c.

Changing foreach to pass-by-ref is not a soln for me as there are too many foreach on my project and I can't grep and modify each of them.

Is there any other handling done for such behaviour on the latest version. Any tool/parser which could highlight them?

Any hints/ideas ?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't modify the array while you are iterating over it. It has undefined behaviour in many languages. PHP is right on both versions. Iterate over the input array and copy the items into a new array or skip them if you need it.

Comment: You have two options: 1) don't upgrade to 7 and fix your code 2) upgrade to 7 and fix your code

Comment: @axiac If I do this, there are n number of places where such handling would be needed. Can I not have a single place(library etc) which restrict foreach() to not change the address of the copied variable(which is being iterated) so that it gets modified inside the loop immediately ?

Comment: @PeeHaa Just thought to ask, I think I need to go for option 2 now. Thanks!

Comment: BTW when I said "fix your code" I meant getting rid of references ;-)

Comment: @PeeHaa Sorry, I didn't get you, `getting rid of references` means should I remove the reference made to the function or modify the foreach stmt to pass `$val` as ref as suggested in the answers ?

Comment: Imo you should just not rely on references like that at all. Just return a new filtered array.

Comment: This was just a snippet for an example, filled array if sent will too behave in the same way. I'll update it right away

Answer (score 9):

Only if you loop the array by reference:     ***foreach ( $array as $key => &$val ) {***

Afaik then NO copy is being made.
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

**BE WARNED**: in this case the $val remains as a pointer to the last element of the array, a best practice is to unset it.

```
foreach ( $array as $key => &$val ) {


<?php

$array = array();
testForeach( $array );

// $array is passed by reference
function testForeach( &$array )
{
    $array = array( 'a', 'b', 'c' );
    foreach ( $array as $key => &$val ) {
        //produces a, b as an output in PHP 5
        //produces a, b, c as an output in PHP 7
        var_dump( $val );

        if ( $val == 'b' ) {
            //remove 'c' from the array
            unset( $array[ 2 ] );
        }
    }
    unset($val);
}
```

Comment: Why in PHP5 yo dont need to pass $val by refrence in foreach?

Answer (score 3):

Beside it seems odd to modify the array while iterating, in PHP 7 you can force a reference in the iterate variable:

```
$array = array('a', 'b', 'c');
foreach ($array as $key => &$val) {
  var_dump($val);
  if ($val == 'b') {
    //remove 'c' from the array
    unset($array[2]);
  }
}
```

Will return on both PHP 5 and 7:

```
string(1) "a"
string(1) "b"
```

See in action on [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Qa0G5).

Comment: where is it written about this difference between php 5 and 7?

Comment: @Alex78191 PHP changelogs maybe